# bash: command not found

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

So I'm running a Raspbian and things are mostly working, however a few days ago I'm suddenly no longer able to run any script when ssh into the machine. I have some script files in `cron.*` folders to run on a schedule and I know they do run as I get emails from some of them. But when I try `cd /etc/cron.weekly` and run the same thing in there, I just get

```
-bash: pibck: command not found
```

I'm not sure what I did to get into this, but it just bugs me that I can't execute stuff manually. I also tried creating brand new files, `chmod 777` but still the same.

To clarify:

- example script was named `pibck`
- `-rwx------ 1 root root 305 Aug 13 22:37 pibck`
- running it like `.\pibck` should work (and has previously)

Comment: Please be more specific about what script you are trying to run, and how you are trying to run it. Is `pibck` the name of a file in the cron directory? Is it executable (provide the output of `ls -l`)? Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> running it like `.\pibck` should work

No. The backslash escapes `p` and vanishes. It effectively does nothing because `p` is not special to the shell. The command is equivalent to `.pibck` which is not what you meant. You meant:

```
./pibck
```

In Unix/Linux the slash character (forward slash, `/`) is used to separate [pathname components](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271). In Windows traditionally it's the backslash (`\`). Most probably this is the root of your confusion. While some tools in Windows may accept both (not necessarily both in one path though) and some tools in Unix/Linux may too, in common Unix *shells* unquoted backslash is the [escape character](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01).